# What is a \r" and why would one use it with a \n?

Tags: javascript, string

What is the difference between this two strings?

`"first line \n second line"` , `"first line \r\n second line"`

Comment: I see it... But I don't know, what is that \r before the \n

Comment: StackOverflow can be a cruel mistress. Typically in a Unix-like environment, '\n' is used for new lines. But in Windows, you usually need '\r\n'. Technically Windows is more accurate here as \n is supposed to just advance one line, but \r returns the cursor to the front of the line as well. Unix usually just flubs that detail.

Comment: If you clarify your question (use the edit link) to be "What is a \r" and why would one use it with a \n?" then you will have a more reasonable question that people won't downvote.  As your question reads now, it looks like you can't see that there's a \r in one string.

Comment: @jfriend00 of course I see the \r in the second, but I don't understand, why is it important

Comment: Danny - I'm trying to point out that if you edit your question to add the real point of your question (you want to know what the \r does and why it would be used), then people will stop downvoting or voting to close your question.  Look at the first comment to your question.  They are mocking your lack of stating what the real question is.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`\r` - Carriage Return
`\n` - Line Feed

`\r\n` is often used in preference to `\n` as it displays properly on both unix and Windows.

Carriage Return just returns the cursor to the beginning of the same line (without advancing to the next line) whereas a Line Feed feeds a new line.

**Note:** *(hover over the grey box below to find out)*

> If you ever get hold of a typewriter, try using it. It is such a magnificent piece of engineering which not many get to experience these days.

Comment: Correct. The carriage return (`\r`) is a reference to the way typewriters' carriages skipped back to the beginning with a *ding*. The writer would next insert a new line (`\n`) in order to not overwrite the previous line. Windows developers liked that idea and decided to see `\r\n` as the way to create a new line. Linux thought this superfluous and got rid of the `\r` character.

Comment: @Honoki Not exactly, the computers also went through a text terminal phase, where the cursor acted as the carriage and CR only made it return to the start of the line, while LF only made it go down a line. Both were actually necessary back then. Then Unix got rid of it by transforming the meaning of LF to be abstract "new line", while DOS and Windows stayed stupid and requiring both. (Even in graphical editors where a standalone CR or LF made no sense and did nothing)
I don't know about Windows 10, but in Windows 7 Notepad *still* required both and read Unix files without newlines at all.

Answer (score 5):

the difference is in the different `EOL` system (Unix like first, Win/DOS second)

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

Its the newline representation for different [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). In windows a new line is \r\n and Linux its \n.

Comment: The slashes go the other way, `\\`

Comment: so this two is strings are the same?

Comment: No, because \r is another character. It's just usually not needed in a Unix environment. The two strings have equivalent content, but different characters.

Comment: @MattGreer No, they have *different* content, *because* they have different characters, but the semantic meaning is usually the same.

Comment: Actually, \r will move a cursor to the beginning of that particular sentence and \n writes content in the new line. So with appending \r before \n will make sure to write that content in new line no matter what's written above it.