# replace with escape character and multiple line

Tags: jquery, replace

I got a html page and I would like to replace several keywords. Below is my coding.
This is my mapping, and I am not sure how to do for multiline.

```
var map = {
    '*|NAME|*':   '%NAME%',
    '*|YEAR|*':   '2014',
},

//multi line replace, how to add into map?
'*|IF:TARGETS|* *|CONTENT:TARGETS|*
*|END:IF|*'
```

This is the replace code.

```
originalText = $("#txt_original").val();
changeText = originalText.replace(/\*|NAME|\*/g, '%NAME%').replace(/\*|YEAR|\*/g, '2014');
```

I got 3 questions in these.

1. How to do proper escape for * , it try *, but the outcome is didn't
   match is what I put.
2. How to search the keywords in multiline ?
3. If my input come with escape character, when I output it, will it result
   the same?

However, it does not work very well like what I expected.
Thanks!

*Update: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vZRdn/

Comment: ya, why the downvote? not helping and give unresponsive response.. maybe the person feel is childish question for them. I am new in javascript.

Comment: can you supply a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: I had supplied jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of researching, I manage to find out the answer by myself.

1. to escape `*|NAME|*` it not only need to escape * , it also require to escape | to the answer is  `/\*\|NAME\|\*/`
2. For multiline the keyword is `\r` or `\n`, but it also depend ur new line situation. You can refer to [What is a \r" and why would one use it with a \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282314/what-is-a-r-and-why-would-one-use-it-with-a-n)

3.What I do is since I am using jQuery, I can simply use `.text()` to escape it.

Hopefully my answer will help other to resolve their problem.